# Pyomo Constraint indexing a Variable by another variables value

Tags: pyomo

I would like to create a constraint of this kind:

```
model.C1 = pyo.Constraint(model.Items, model.ItemOffsets,
    rule = lambda model, item, offset: 
        model.p[offset + model.x[item]] * model.ItemUsage[item, offset] == model.ItemValues[item, offset])
```

I receive the following error message:

```
ERROR: Rule failed when generating expression for constraint
    ConstrPayloadLayout with index (0, 0): RuntimeError: Error retrieving the
    value of an indexed item p: index 0 is not a constant value.  This is
    likely not what you meant to do, as if you later change the fixed value of
    the object this lookup will not change.  If you understand the
    implications of using non-constant values, you can get the current value
    jof the object using the value() function.
ERROR: Constructing component 'ConstrPayloadLayout' from data=None failed:
    RuntimeError: Error retrieving the value of an indexed item p: index 0 is
    not a constant value.  This is likely not what you meant to do, as if you
    later change the fixed value of the object this lookup will not change.
    If you understand the implications of using non-constant values, you can
    get the current value of the object using the value() function.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyomo/core/base/indexed_component.py", line 382, in __getitem__
    obj = self._data.get(index, _NotFound)
TypeError: unhashable type: '_GeneralVarData'
```

Is there a way to define a constraint with a non-constant index in Pyomo?

Comment: Not possible.  You'll have to reformulate your model a bit.

Comment: Yeah I had an alternative model which could be implemented using the GDP implementation of pyomo - just thought that this way the LP is smarter until I noticed this problem. Thanks a lot!